# 「ようとしている」vs.「そうになっている」についての質問です

Tags: grammar

「〜ようとする」は無意志動詞と一緒に使うと「もうすぐ〜になる（状態）」という意味になりますね。

> 太陽が沈もうとしている

この例文の「ようとしている」を「そうになっている」に置き換えると、語感はどうなるでしょう？

> 太陽が沈みそうになっている

**「ようとしている」**と**「そうになっている」** のニュアンスの違いを教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「～ようとする」は擬人観を感じさせる表現、感覚・理性可能なものじゃないけれどもそういうふうに比喩的に聞こえるような言い方でぎりぎり成功できた雰囲気が染まっています。「～そうになった」はもっと事実をそのまま伝えているだけです。

もし言っていること間違ったいたら他の方に是非指摘して欲しいんですが、「そうになっている」は方言っぽく聞こえて「そういうふうになっている」の短縮だと思います。（群馬出身の母からその台詞をよく聞いていた）。

Translating to accommodate English-readers, the question was about "ようとする" vs. "そうになる":

ようとする is more anthropomorphic; in the example the sentence is making the sun seem like it is struggling to rise to have its light shone across the Earth, whereas そうになる is merely stating facts of physical actions dispassionately.

Comment: 無意識動詞を意向形に活用してきたわけで擬人化なように気がするという意味ですか

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございます。(*^▽^*)

Answer (score 2):

「沈みそうになっている」と言うと、沈むことが望ましくないような印象になります。

Comment: 早速のお返事有難うございます。よく勉強しました。(*^▽^*)